# I want query to store data in different rows in database.

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a query to deposit cash into an account. In this we provide pin as verification and amount to deposit. I use `atm_transaction_details_tb` table for deposit as well as withdraw(I use a similar type of query to withdraw . 
deposit query->

```
selectQuery = "update atm_transaction_details_tb set amount=amount+?, dot=?,
               deposit=? where pin=? ";
```

withdraw query->

```
 selectQuery = "update atm_transaction_details_tb set amount=amount+?, dot=?,
               deposit=? where pin=? ";
```

The query is correct but after performing the query I see that that withdraw and deposit comes in same line in database , I want it in separate row. The tables similar to database is shown below -

```
I am getting this in database-
Amount  DOT        Withdraw Deposit PIN
6000    12-Sep-2013 500 500 5555

I want this in database - 
Amount  DOT        Withdraw Deposit PIN
5500    12-Sep-2013     500 5555
5000    12-Sep-2013 500     5555
```

I want the query to store data in different row. May be the query need to be modified to make the change. Please help me out in this as I am a newbie . Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you want it in different row, you should try to do a insert. update will edit the existing row.

Comment: How about using a COMMIT?  - http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_4010.htm this would force the first transaction to be committed to the database and then for your second, it should generate a new row.

Comment: You want an insert instead of update. This is really a newbie question. You shoud start reading some fundamentals...

Comment: @FlorinGhita This is not a newbie question, because you didn't understood the question properly so you said it as newbie. I wanted to insert a row which will also update the amount field based on the pin number if it is present in database. check the table properly.

Answer (score 0):

```
selectQuery = "INSERT INTO atm_transaction_details_tb (amount, dot, deposit, pin) 
VALUES(5500,'2013-09-12',500,5555)"
```

or

```
INSERT INTO atm_transaction_details_tb (amount, dot, deposit, pin) 
SELECT TOP 1 
    amount + 500
    , '2013-09-12'
    , 500
    , pin FROM atm_transaction_details 
WHERE pin=5555 
ORDER BY dot DESC
```

the TOP 1 and ORDER BY is important. Otherwise you will insert multiple rows for one transaction. If there are more than one transactions on one day, you also need some identity column to find the last transaction.

Also I am not a big fan of your database design. You have the "Balance" of the account stored for every transaction. But you can better make a query that calculates the balance, or store the balance in a different table.

Comment: I am using a pin to query and then insert into the database , how can i do in the one you provided above?. Further more your query says , missing.

Answer (score 0):

Use insert query instead of update. Because update will change the values of the same row/ rows based on the condition.

Answer (score 0):

first time use Update Query as you are using right

```
UPDATE 
  atm_transaction_details_tb 
SET
  amount = amount + 50,
  dot = '2013-09-12',
  deposit = 50 
WHERE pin = 15
```

After this above query, run insert Query that copy the above query record using the above pin id not update the query again, Only insert like below.

```
INSERT INTO `atm_transaction_details_tb` (`pin`, `amount`, `dot`, `deposit`) 
  (SELECT 
    `pin`,
    `amount`,
    `dot`,
    `deposit` 
  FROM
    atm_transaction_details_tb 
  WHERE pin = 15) ;
```